# Changing the text of a JLabel and status of JMenuItem during runtime

Tags: java, swing, dynamic, jlabel, jmenuitem

I am developing an application in which I would like to display the username on the top of the screen after the user has logged into the system. Also I need to enable five JMenuItems only after the user has been logged in. I used the following code and called it from the successful logon If condition but it does no change to the application at all.

NOTE :- The username is to be displayed in the JFrame and the login form is a JInternalFrame
All JMenuItems are also in the JFrame

obj2 is the object created for the LoginModel class in order to retrieve the username

```
private String global_username="";
public String getGlobalUsername(){
    return global_username;
}
```

The method which I call to change the state of the JMenuItems and to set the value of the JLabel

```
public void disableMenues(){
        mntmSupplierManagement.setEnabled(false);
        mntmEmployeeManagement.setEnabled(false);
        mntmStockManagement.setEnabled(false);
        mntmReporting.setEnabled(false);
        mntmTransaction.setEnabled(false);
        userName.setText("Logged in as "+obj2.getGlobalUsername());
}
```

I used the code below in the JInternalFrame (Login form) in order to call the above method after the user has been logged on

```
 if(username.equals(user)&&password.equals(pass)){
        System.out.println("Logged into the system");
        global_username=username;
        accountType=acc;
        updateView();
else{
        System.out.println("Unsuccessful login");                            
        updateView();
}
```

Also I used the following code to create the JLabel

```
JLabel userName=new JLabel();
userName.setText("Logged in as "+obj2.getGlobalUsername());
```

This gave me a NullPointerException so I changed it to

```
userName.setText("Logged in as ");
```

Any Help is Greatly Appreciated

Thanks in Advance Everyone!!!

Comment: *"Any Help is Greatly Appreciated"*  Any [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html) is Likely to be Closely Examined.

Comment: @Andrew I do not actually know what you referring to but anyhow my code which I have given despite it being long is necessary to explain what my problem is

Comment: You haven't included too much code, but you haven't necessarily included all the relevant pieces that constitute an SSCCE. For example, the class type for obj2 and its class variable declarations. I think this is what @Andrew was referring too. For your NPE, it would seem `obj2` is null, but I really can't say why from the code you've shown.

Comment: @Yoosuf *"despite it being long"*  An SSCCE can easily be 100 lines of code (i.e. more code than you have included).  The SSCCE would give us all the information we need to determine what `obj2` is, and why it is `null`.  (Note, I inferred the last parts of that from what @Perception commented - I have not tried to decipher the code snippets.)

Comment: Im sorry actually I went through the SSCCE link and I also edited the above question and included the obj2 class and the reason why I need it for as well. Thanks

Comment: Again obj2 is null. Again, you have not given us enough information to be able to do more than guess, and likely that would be done poorly. Best of luck.

Comment: SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example) The most important operative word that is lacking here is the one in () Compilable. This makes it easy for others to see what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend having a single variable to track whether the user is logged in or not and then bind your components appropriately

```
private boolean loggedIn = false;

public void disableMenues(){
    mntmSupplierManagement.setEnabled(!loggedIn);
    mntmEmployeeManagement.setEnabled(!loggedIn);
    mntmStockManagement.setEnabled(!loggedIn);
    mntmReporting.setEnabled(!loggedIn);
    mntmTransaction.setEnabled(!loggedIn);
    userName.setText("Logged in as "+obj2.getGlobalUsername());
}
```

I would also suggest to track the LoginModel class throughout the session

```
private LoginModel lm = null;

private void authenticate(String username, String password){
    //check username password (database maybe)
    //and return the LoginModel for the pair
    lm = returnedLoginModel;
}
```

And then in the JFrame all you have to do is

```
if(lm != null){
    System.out.println("Logged into the system");
    loggedIn = true;
    updateView();
else{
    System.out.println("Unsuccessful login");
    loggedIn = false;                            
    updateView();
}
```

Keep in mind that you have to track the logout as well

```
private void logout(){
    lm = null;
}
```